# Is there a python code for point biserial correlation adjusting covariates?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, pearson-correlation

I have a binary variable (which is either 0 or 1) and continuous variables. I have continuous variables that I should adjust as covariates. I would like to see the result of the point biserial correlation. scipy.stats.pointbiserialr is well used for point biserial correlation but I'm afraid they do not support adjusting covariates.

So my questions are,

1. Is it okay to use Pearson correlation in this case?
2. Is there an alternative option that I can use, in scipy.stats.pointbiserialr for controlling the covariates?
3. Is there other python modules that I can use for this purpose?

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Note that a question should only contain ONE question (unless they are really tightly related and can be seen as one). Your third question is a library recommendation which is off-topic here. As explained in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), "_focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do._"